# Why can't Gradle find existing artifact?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I posted the same question at the Gradle Forums [Gradle can not find existing artifact?](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-can-not-find-existing-artifact/34014).

Gradle v4.10.2

This really bothers me, since I know it should work, and I feel like I’m setting up my build.gradle file correctly.

I built a plugin and deployed it to our AWS S3 Maven repo.

[image: Artiface in AWS S3]

When I run a Gradle command, e.g., `./gradlew clean`, I get

[image: Gradle failure]

Here's my `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url s3_bucket
      credentials(AwsCredentials) {
        accessKey AWS_ACCESS_KEY
        accessKey AWS_SECRET_KEY
      }
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.zift.utilities:zift-version-plugin:0.0.1"
  }
}
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'maven'
  id 'maven-publish'
  id 'java-gradle-plugin'
}

version = '0.0.1'

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'artifactId': project.artifactId,
               'groupId': project.groupId,
               'version': project.version
  }
  baseName artifactId
  doLast {
    println "artifactId: $project.artifactId\ngroupId: $project.groupId\nversion: $version"
  }
}
```

If I comment out the `classpath` line (the problematic line), I get

```
$ ./gradlew build

> Task :jar
:jar: No valid plugin descriptors were found in META-INF/gradle-plugins
artifactId: zift-version-plugin
groupId: com.zift.utilities
version: 0.0.1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you post your build.gradle file? it looks like you have a version mismatch

Comment: @MartínZaragoza, yeah sorry I forgot to put it in my original post, but have added it now.